# $|f(z)|\leq|\frac{1}{z}|\Rightarrow f(z)=c\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and $|f(z)|\leq|\frac{1}{z}|$ for every $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Prove: There is a $c\in\mathbb{C}, |c|\leq1,$ so that $f(z)=c\frac{1}{z}$ for every $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

I know that this type of problem is usually solved using Liouville's theorem by defining $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, z\mapsto zf(z)$. However, $f$ is not a entire function here.  I tried to solve the problem with Riemann's singualrity theorem but unfortunately I didn't get any result. Is there another possible solution? Especially since the equality only has to be shown for all $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$...
Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riemann's Theorem on removable singularities show that $g(z)=zf(z)$ for $z \neq 0$, $g(0)=c$ defines an entire function for some $c$ (since it is bounded in some deleted neighborhood of $0$). Liouvile's Theorem applied to this function shows that $zf(z)$ is a constant.